# Can I disable Chromium's in-browser mp3 player?

Tags: chromium, mp3, mime-type

When I click on a link in Chromium to an mp3, can I make the default behavior be to download it and not to start playing it with some in-browser thing?

I've disabled all of my plugins, so it's not one of them trying to play the file.  And I suppose I could always right-click or control-click or what have you -- but the problem isn't that I don't know how to download the file (if I were desperate and/or crazy I would just curl it), the problem is that Chromium seems to think that one of its roles is to play mp3s for me.  I just want to set it straight.

Chromium Version:  18.0.1025.168 (Developer Build 134367 Linux) Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option does not exist, and from what I gather it is intentionally left out and will not be added.

You can alt-click any link to store the file directly, disregarding its type (mp3, avi, pdf, html, ...).

It was of course not confirmed, but supposedly, this is done to keep the user inside the browser and extend the browsers control of the user. Reading the EULA supports this.

Comment: Further reading: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=176790

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to, but I think its a bug.  If you type about:plugins in the address bar, and disabled the mp3 plugin it will not work.  I have tried it.  You can try it yourself and see.  In the mean time a workaround is to right-click the file and choose save link as, and that will do it.

Comment: I didn't have an mp3 plugin entry, but I just moved everything out of /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins to be certain.  This leaves "Remoting Viewer" as the sole entry in about:plugins, but the problem persists.

Comment: I completely agree with you, though, that this is buggy behavior - any idea where the bugreport is?