# How does Chromium pick a MIME-type handler?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, plugins, mime-type

Chromium doesn't seem to have any obvious MIME-type configuration settings, which strikes me as a little broken.  My specific problem is that there are a number of filetypes that Chromium plays in-browser that I'd rather either download or associate with whatever my system-default MIME-type would suggest.  Can this be done?

And here are two related (unanswered) questions, asking if there's a way to tell Chromium not to play [mpeg video](https://askubuntu.com/q/120225/) and [mp3](https://askubuntu.com/q/139436/) files.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this [ArchWiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chromium) in the section on **File associations**. To quote from there:

> Unlike Firefox, Chromium does not maintain its own database of
>   mimetype-to-application associations. Instead, it relies on Xdg-open
>   to open files and other mime types, for example, magnet links. See
>   Xdg-open for more information.
>
> There are exceptions to this rule though. In the case of mailto URIs
>   chromium calls out to xdg-email which is similar to xdg-open. Other
>   protocol handlers may have equivalent scripts so check /usr/bin/xdg*. 
>   ...

Comment: No - wait - Chromium is still broken for those mimetypes where it has some sort of builtin player (see [related](http://askubuntu.com/q/120225/).  My thought at first was something like "oh hey - `xdg-mime query default audio/mpeg` gives me `totem.desktop` and Chromium is somehow deciding that this means it should use its (disabled) Totem plugin to play these in-browser - so I changed to `xdg-mime default banshee.desktop audio/mpeg` but still get the obnoxious builtin player.  Which, in the first place, all I want is to download the file rather than try to open it.

Comment: Has anyone found a resolution for this? Chromium automatically handles audio/mpeg files with a tiny rectangular player. The position slider is extremely small and the knob is too large; magnifying the page magnifies everything proportionally, so the knob covers just as much as before. I can find plenty of apps that intercept matching content, e.g. "right click -> open in VLC", but no way to actually replace the handler. Is this what you're talking about? It's been five years! (And on that note, the "related" link is dead.)